# Relation between finite abelian group and its set of linear characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and denote by $G^{\times}$ its set of linear characters, i.e. homomorphisms $\phi : G \to \mathbb C^{\times}$, where $\mathbb C^{\times}$ denotes the multplicative group of the complex numbers. Then these form an orthonormal set with respect to the inner product
$$
 \langle \chi, \phi \rangle := \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \chi(g) \overline{ \phi(g)}.
$$
In [these lecture notes](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gind2_2.html) by Daniel Bump it is proven that $|G^{\times}| \le |G|$, this is part of the proof of Proposition 2.2.3, namelely that $|G| = |G^{\times}|$ and that $G \cong (G^{\times})^{\times}$. The argument goes like this:

> We first observe that $|G^{\times}| \le |G|$ since the linear characters are an orthonormal set, hence lineary independent.

I do not get it, what is the connection between linear independence of the characters and the cardinality of $|G|$? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Characters live in the vector space of all functions $G \to \mathbb{C}$, which has dimension $|G|$.

Comment: Hope they have a life worth living there, thanks for your comment! :)