# The character group of $G$ for an abelian group $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, proof-explanation, characters

> **Problem Statement**: Prove that the one-dimensional characters of a group $G$ form a group under multiplication of functions, i.e. where the group operation is: 
>   $$(\chi\cdot\chi')(g)=\chi(g)\chi'(g)$$
>   This group is called the character group of $G$, and is often denoted by $\hat{G}$. Prove that if $G$ is abelian, then $|\hat{G}|=|G|$.

So, I completely understand how to prove that $\hat{G}$ is a group, but I am unsure about the second part: proving that if $G$ is abelian, then $|\hat{G}|=|G|$.

Clearly, $\hat{G}$ is abelian regardless of $G$ being abelian, since $\hat{G}\subset\mathbb{C}^\times$ and $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is commuative. So $G$ being abelian eliminates the possibility that $(\chi\cdot\chi')(gh)=(\chi\cdot\chi')(hg)$ with $gh\neq hg$.

So basically, to prove that $|\hat{G}|=|G|$, we must show that for any distinct $g,h\in G$, then $(\chi\cdot\chi')(g)\neq(\chi\cdot\chi')(h)$, but I am unsure how I should approach this type of proof.

I was thinking somehow prove that there is an isomorphism between $G$ and $\hat{G}$, but my professor said that constructing a homomorphism between the two groups would be too difficult without using material that we haven't learned yet.

Any suggestions for showing that $|\hat{G}|=|G|$ are appreciated!

Comment: Have you studied the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups? If you can show it is true for cyclic groups, and show that $|\widehat{G\times H}| = |\widehat G| \times |\widehat H|$ for groups $G,H$, then the result follows.

Comment: No, I don't believe we have studied that. I am not familiar with that notation.
One thing also confusing me, one-dimensional characters are defined by the group $G$, since the elements in a representation of $G$ are just $1\times 1$ matrices so for $A\in G$, $\chi(A)=\mathrm{tr}(A)$ which is just the matrix entry. Wouldn't that mean that $G$ is always abelian?

Comment: The notation is just your notation (my hats are wider than yours) - $\widehat{ G\times H}$ is the group of characters of the group $G\times H$. The structure theorem states that every finitely generated abelian group is a product of cyclic groups (with some extra properties). I guess this is what your professor was referring to by material you haven't learnt yet.

Comment: See also Proposition $2.2.3$ of Bump's lecture notes cited  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470964/relation-between-finite-abelian-group-and-its-set-of-linear-characters?rq=1).

Comment: In answer to your second question, the term character has two meanings: first is a group homomorphism from $G\to \mathbb C^\times$. The second is the trace of a group representation. The latter is not generally a group homomorphism, since $\mathrm{tr}(AB)$ is not generally equal to $\mathrm{tr}(BA)$.

Comment: Yes, but if it is a one-dimensional character, wouldn't it always be true that $\mathrm{tr}(AB)=\mathrm{tr}(BA)$, since $A,B\in GL_1(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}^\times \setminus \left\{0\right\}$?

Comment: Yes that's true. How would you conclude that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: Well, since $\hat{G}\subset\mathbb{C}^\times \setminus \left\{ 0\right\}$ and since $\mathbb{C}^\times \setminus \left\{ 0\right\}$ is commutative then $\hat{G}$ is commutative? Then for distinct $g,h\in G$, we must have that $\chi(g)\neq\chi(h)$, but since $\hat{G}$ are all products of characters, we must show that $(\chi\cdot\chi')(g)\neq(\chi\cdot\chi')(h)$? Which I guess could be proven easily if you claim that for distinct $g,h\in G$, we must have that $\chi(g)\neq\chi(h)$?

Comment: The character will almost certainly not be faithful! It doesn't make sense to say $G\subset \mathbb C^\times$.

Comment: Would $\hat{G}$ not be a subset of $\mathbb{C}^\times$?

Comment: No. $\widehat G$ consists of homomorphisms from $G\to \mathbb C^\times$. It is not a subset of $\mathbb C^\times$.